# .NET Core odbc for Linux exists?

Tags: linux, odbc, informix, .net-core

I need access to Informix with .NET Core on Linux.
But IBM doesn't started to develop driver for .NET Core.
On windows, i know ODBC with OdbcConnection.
On linux, it's possible to configure odbc for Informix.
But OdbcConnection doesn't exists for Windows and Linux in .NET Core.
Any solution for OdbcConnection in .NET Core? (because it will be a good solution to get driver for all provider)

Comment: That's something you should push IBM on, or you step up to write your own ADO.NET provider

Comment: RHEL has been doing some stuff with windows .NET maybe give them a look but you are most likely gonna have to go open source or if you are paying IBM for support open an issue.

Comment: There are third-party options, such as the Enterprise Edition ADO.NET Provider [for Informix](http://uda.openlinksw.com/dotnet-informix-mt/), [for ODBC Data Sources](http://uda.openlinksw.com/dotnet-odbc-mt/), and [for JDBC Data Sources](http://uda.openlinksw.com/dotnet-jdbc-mt/) from my employer, [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/). Other options also exist, from us and various others.

Comment: IBM release a nuget : https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core/ . Good news but not tested on informix for the moment. More details here : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/DB2DotnetCore?lang=en